# Merging two DataTables into a DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, datatable, wpfdatagrid

I have two DataTables in a DataSet in C# (the first DataTable contains a unique set of identifiers and some associated data, but the second DataTable will contain more than one record per foreign key identifier), and what I'd like to do is use a DataGrid to display all of the data from the first DataTable and have a column in that DataGrid that displays the data from the second DataTable in a dropdown box.

Is this even possible, and if so, how would you recommend doing this?

I've looked at doing a JOIN but it seems to violate the constraints of having unique records.

Comment: I don't see how this is not constructive.

Comment: Why not use two datagrids in a parent-child relationship? Ex. clicking on an entry in the first (unique rows) grid will display all related rows in the second one.

Comment: @L.B: because I don't have time right now. I also don't see how code would help this.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, OK, I guess this question will wait till you have time...

Comment: Have you tried to datasource your combo column from the second table, while having relationship in dataset established? I might be wrong, but it may be possible. Or, even datasource the combo column to a dataview based on mother record of the first table. Truly, havn't played with datagrids in some time.

Comment: @rontornambe, definitely a good thought there.  Seems like a bit of a waste to add the additional table for only 1 column in the second datatable, but if that's the way it must be done, then I guess that's what I'll have to live with.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @T.S. Hmm, I've tried something similar, but I'll look at that option a little bit more

Comment: It doesn't have to be done that way. If there is only one column of data, perhaps a ListBox would be a better choice; a combo-box can also be used if it fits your UI better. I am assuming the form is for display only purposes.

Comment: You definitely can set the bind to have a path=dataSet relation with the source equal to the parent table and have it work the way you want. But you'll need to do something about your problem with creating the relationship first.

Comment: You can establish a data relation and getchildrows.   But not sure how the to bind that in XAML.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.getchildrows(v=vs.71).aspx